# Bash script: How do I get a script to check for duplicate file names of different formats?

Tags: bash, macos, file

So I have a conversion program (works through command line) that takes a data file and converts it into a new format while also putting it in a folder with various subfolders.  I wanted to create a script that would check for duplicates before executing this conversion program.

So far, I have

```
#!/bin/bash
for subj in `ls <directory to data files>`
do
        subj_name=$subj
        subj_path=<directory to data files>/$subj_name #I need this for my program, can ignore


        cd <directory with output folders>

        if [ -e “$subj” ]; then
             echo “This file already exists” #This will restart the loop and move to the next file
        else
             echo “This folder does not exist”
             My_Program #I can handle this one
        fi
done
```

The program works fine with files of the same format (ie .txt and .txt) but cannot check for a folder and .txt for the same name.  Are there any changes I can make to check for the same name regardless of file format?

Edit: I did a little experimenting, and I put a duplicate data file into the directory with the output folders and it still didn't recognize it.  I think the cd line or the if line is wrong then.. anyone have any tips on how I could fix this?

Comment: Manipulate the filename to include only the name and not the suffix, this can be achieved through string manipulation, do a google search for "bash string manipulation".

Answer (score 3):

Use the syntax bellow to remove ".txt" from the end of value of $subj, returning the resulting string . (more info on "[Bash String Manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)")

```
${subj%.txt}
```

Then check the existence of files/directories with or without .txt:

```
if [ -e "$subj" ] || [ -e "${subj%.txt}" ]; then
....
```

If you want to remove any suffix (.txt, .tgz, ...) use `${subj%.*}` to delete all characters after (and including) the last '.' Example:

```
[bash]$ subj=file.txt
[bash]$ echo ${subj%.*}
[bash]$ file
```

Or use `${subj%%.*}` to delete all characters after (and including) the first '.':

```
[bash]$ subj=file.txt.tgz
[bash]$ echo ${subj%%.*}
[bash]$ file
```

Comment: That's a great bash string manipulation link, +1. Although, I don't think I would remove the suffix from the string altogether, in case you need it later. I would just do `if [ -e ${subj%.txt} ] ; then` (not sure if that syntax is correct). I also wouldn't just remove the `.txt` suffix, I would remove all suffixes using the string manipulation that removes everything after the last period.

Comment: i edited with your suggestion. thanks. what would be the regex to remove any suffix?

Comment: @BrunoNegrãoZica `${subj%.*}` will remove all characters after last `.` use `${subj%%.*}` to remove all characters from first `.`